# VBA Loop Through Array of Shape Names

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I am trying to loop through an array list of shapes, but I keep getting the error "Subscript out of range" when the function, ShapeExists is encountered. The code runs fine if I execute the ShapeExists function, by itself. What am I doing wrong?

```
 Sub Workbook_Open() 
    Debug.Print "Begin Workbook_Open sub." 
    Dim ws As Worksheet 
    Dim wsCount As Integer 
    Dim shapeList As Variant 
    Dim element As Variant 
     
    CheckFirstRun = True 
     
    wsCount = Sheets.Count 
    Debug.Print "Number of Sheets: " & wsCount 

    shapeList = Array("exportData", "InitializeData")

        Debug.Print "Making sure the Initilize and Export buttons are hidden." 
        For i = 1 To wsCount 
            For Each element In shapeList 
                Debug.Print "Working to hide shape " & element 
                If ShapeExists(element) = True Then 
                    Debug.Print element & " exists. Working to hide." 
                    HideShapes (element) 
                End If 
            Next element 
            'Sheets(i).Shapes("exportData").Visible = False 
            'Sheets(i).Shapes("InitializeData").Visible = False 
        Next i  
    Debug.Print "End Workbook_Open sub." 
End Sub 
  
Sub HideShapes(shapeName As Variant) 
    Sheets(i).Shapes(shapeName).Visible = False 
End Sub 
  
Function ShapeExists(shapeName As Variant) As Boolean 
    Dim sh As Shape 
    For Each sh In Sheets(i).Shapes 
        If sh.Name = shapeName Then ShapeExists = True 
        Debug.Print ShapeExists 
    Next sh 
End Function
```

Comment: Are you using `i` as a module-level variable? Personally I wouldn't do that, I'd add a `Worksheet` parameter to `ShapeExists` and pass it the appropriate sheet. Also I'd use a `For... Next` loop to iterate over an array, not `For Each...Next`.

Comment: Side note: `HideShapes (element) ` should be `HideShapes element`, no parentheses.

Comment: So why do you not run in deubg mode through it? Then you know where it goes wrong..

Comment: The issue was, i was not declared as a public variable. At the top of the module, before the first sub, setting, `Public i as integer` fixed the issue, but what are the security implications of declaring i as a public variable? I suppose functions in VB can not see the looping variable, even if they are called inside the loop, without the variable being made public? ... @Albert I'm New to VBA. I had no idea I could do that until you suggested it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that while you can add a Global variable `i`, it's generally considered bad practice and it would be better to change your subroutines to add a parameter so you can pass in the sheet number as well as the shape name:

```
Sub HideShapes(wsNumber As Long, shapeName As Variant) 
    ThisWorkBook.WorkSheets(wsNumber).Shapes(shapeName).Visible = False 
End Sub
```

Then call like:

```
HideShapes i, element 'no parentheses!
```

Also note it's good to always be explicit about which workbook you mean to affect (even though it's not strictly necessary in  the ThisWorkbook code module)

Likewise `Sheets` vs `Worksheets` - the first also includes Chart sheets if present.

Here's a slightly different approach:

```vb
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Worksheet
    Dim shapeList As Variant
    Dim element As Variant
     
    Debug.Print "Begin Workbook_Open sub."
    'CheckFirstRun = True
    shapeList = Array("exportData", "InitializeData")
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'easier loop
        For Each element In shapeList
            On Error Resume Next  'ignore error if no matching shape
            ws.Shapes(element).Visible = False
            On Error GoTo 0       'stop ignoring errors
        Next element
    Next ws
    Debug.Print "End Workbook_Open sub."
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks much more elegant that what I had. ;-) Thank you!